# How to Junit for new object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

Wanted to understand how to write JUnit test case when a new object is passed to the controller.

Following is the piece of code from the Spring MVC controller which pass new PriceIncrease object.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/priceincrease")
public String showPriceIncreasePage(Map<String, Object> map){
    map.put("priceIncrease", new PriceIncrease());

    logger.info("Returning Price Increase home page");
    return priceIncreasePage;
}
```

Unit test I have is, which is certainly incorrect as it will fail.

```
@Test
public void testShowPriceIncreasePage(){
    String viewName = inventoryController.showPriceIncreasePage(model);

    /* Expecting to return the new object of PriceIncrease*/
    assertEquals(new PriceIncrease(), model.get("priceIncrease"));

    //assertEquals(InventoryController.priceIncreasePage, viewName);
}
```

Should we be using when to ensure that same object is return in the Junit test.  I am not sure that this is correct way.

```
@Test
public void testShowPriceIncreasePage(){
    String viewName = inventoryController.showPriceIncreasePage(model);

    /* Expecting to return the new object of PriceIncrease*/
    PriceIncrease priceIncrease = new PriceIncrease();
    when(model.get("priceIncrease")).thenReturn(priceIncrease);
    assertEqual(priceIncrease, model.get("priceIncrease"));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Writing good tests is an extremely broad subject, one that you should really dive into if you ever want to write really good and useful tests.

For the sake of your example:

- name of the test should not begin with 'test' unless you are using JUnit 3.x. JUnit 4.x provides `@Test` annotation to mark test methods,
- name of the test should tell the reader what is that you are expecting from the unit under test,
- test should follow a `given / when / then` structure. `given`: in this block you setup state of the system, `when`: is the place where you call your code that is to be tested, `then`: is the place where you evaluate results (all the asserts should go here)
- you want to assert that both the value returned from controller's method is equal to the "desired" one and that your model contains a particular object,
- I don't see any code for `PriceIncrease` but I assume it does not have a `equals` / `hashCode` methods implemented? If such is the case, the code will not work.
- Adding `equals` / `hashCode` to `PriceIncrease` will help you with the test you are writing

Your test should look more less like this:

```
@Test
public void shouldRedirectToPriceIncreasePageWithModelValuesSetCorrectly(){
    // given
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();

    // when
    String viewName = inventoryController.showPriceIncreasePage(model);

    // then
    assertEqual(viewName, "some-view-name");
    assertEqual(model.get("priceIncrease"), new PriceIncrease());
    assertEqual(model.size(), 1);
}
```

If you want to improve your test writing skills then consider these books by Tomasz Kaczanowski:

- [Practical Unit Testing with JUnit and Mockito](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8393489393)
- [Bad Tests, Good Tests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IDFKRY8)